# Handle custom Error message on Bad request

Tags: delphi, indy, bad-request, delphi-10.4-sydney, idhttp

I'm developing an Android app (Client). The server works with C#. When I make some request specifically some Posts, I'm getting an error message on bad request such as 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' which is okay when the item I searched for is incorrect. But on bad request the server sends me also a message body in JSON, something like this:

```
  {
    "responseMessage":"The item you searched not found"
  }
```

Is there a way to get this message (and NOT the bad request message 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') and show it as a response of bad request? The back end works fine, I check it on Postman. My code of Post request is this:

```
  Json := '{ '+
          ' "code":"'+str+'",'+
          ' "userid":'+userid+''+
          ' } ';
  JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(Json, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
   IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
   IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

   try

   sResponse := IdHTTP1.Post('http://....', JsonToSend);

   except      
       on e  : Exception  do
        begin
             ShowMessage(e.Message); // this message is : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
             Exit;
        end;

   end;

  finally
  JsonToSend.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: `HTTP 400` is `Bad Request`, while `HTTP 404 Not Found` exactly means that and not more - it doesn't imply a "_bad request_", nor when the requested resource will be available. Also the text must not be like that - you could also serve `HTTP 404 No posts found`. Also sure you want to request `http` and not `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the JSON content on errors, you have 2 options:

1. Catch the raised `EIdHTTPProtocolException` and read the JSON from its `ErrorMessage` property, not the `Message` property:

   ```
   try
     sResponse := IdHTTP1.Post(...);
   except      
     on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
     begin
       sResponse := E.ErrorMessage;
     end;
     on E: Exception do
     begin
       ShowMessage(e.Message);
       Exit;
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. Enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property to prevent `TIdHTTP.Post()` from raising `EIdHTTPProtocolException` on HTTP failures, and instead just return the JSON to your `sResponse` variable.  You can use the `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode` property to detect HTTP failures, if needed:

   ```
   IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

   try
     sResponse := IdHTTP1.Post(...);
     if IdHTTP1.ResponseCode <> 200 then ...
   except      
     on E: Exception do
       ...
   end;
   ```